# How can I set conditions for dataframes?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

/we.tl/t-ghXIOjPznq

Here is my xlsx file.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaaEu.jpg

I have such a dataframe. I want to define only for conditions where LITHOLOGY column is 1. In order to do that;

```
df2 = pd.read_excel('V131BLOG.xlsx')

LITHOLOGY = [1] & 

df2[df2.LITHOLOGY.isin(LITHOLOGY)]
```

There hasn't been a problem so far. I was able to filter as I wanted.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVAc0.jpg

In addition to these, I want to see cells with LITHOLOGY column as 1 If It's thickness is bigger than 15cms. What I mean is that, the cumulative difference of consecutive cells of DEPTH_MD column should be bigger than 10cms. I have not made any progress on this. What path should I follow?

As you can see in this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/k70Y4.jpg) figure, there can be seen serial group of LITHOLOGY column as 1. But when you check the DEPTH_MD values, upper group is equal to 10cms, on the other side, lower group is equal 5cms. I want to create a dataframe that only contains bigger than 10cms DEPTH_MD values.

Input:

```
        DEPTH_MD CALIPER GR     LITHOLOGY SHALLOW   DEEP
1980    329.00  26.8964 25.47160    2   2.99103 2.62130
1981    329.05  26.8574 32.54390    2   2.94772 2.58945
1982    329.10  27.1297 28.83750    1   2.90123 2.55601
1983    329.15  26.9742 17.91150    2   2.80383 2.52327
1984    329.20  28.3946 31.94310    2   2.76041 2.49050
1985    329.25  30.9402 17.63760    1   2.71992 2.46051
1986    329.30  35.2419 17.69170    1   2.67355 2.42852
1987    329.35  37.9206 17.74620    1   2.61838 2.33619
1988    329.40  39.9189 24.84460    2   2.56200 2.28671
1989    329.45  41.4947 7.03354     2   2.50669 2.23887
1990    329.50  41.5473 7.03354     2   2.42167 2.19944
1991    329.55  41.0158 10.58260    2   2.40039 2.17235
```

Output except:

```
        DEPTH_MD CALIPER GR  LITHOLOGY SHALLOW  DEEP
1985    329.25  30.9402 17.6376 1   2.71992 2.46051
1986    329.30  35.2419 17.6917 1   2.67355 2.42852
1987    329.35  37.9206 17.7462 1   2.61838 2.33619
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of your dataframe in code, not picture. An example of the expected result would also help. Your problem/request is not very clear...

Comment: I tried to add my file to post via wetransfer

Comment: Input and output except are added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group the consecutive 'LITHOLOGY' rows then compute the thickness and finally broadcast to all rows:

```
df['THICKNESS'] = (
    df.groupby(df['LITHOLOGY'].ne(df['LITHOLOGY'].shift()).cumsum())['DEPTH_MD'] 
      .transform(lambda x: x.diff().sum())
)

out = df[(df['LITHOLOGY'] == 1) & (df['THICKNESS'] >= 0.1)]
```

Output:

```
>>> out
      DEPTH_MD  CALIPER       GR  LITHOLOGY  SHALLOW     DEEP  THICKNESS
1985    329.25  30.9402  17.6376          1  2.71992  2.46051        0.1
1986    329.30  35.2419  17.6917          1  2.67355  2.42852        0.1
1987    329.35  37.9206  17.7462          1  2.61838  2.33619        0.1
```

Comment: Sure, I also want to group the units which have same repetitive thickness. For example, If It's thickness is bigger than 0.1, It should called that interval as BED1 from 329.25 to 329.35.  And should say BED2 to interval just after coming first interval. Can you reproduce?